# Java MSI install error 3: -2147287037

Tags: java, msi

We want to silent install Java 8 update 60 via its msi.
The installation stops with a vague error which isn't very helpful at finding a solution.

This is the MSI log:

```
=== Verbose logging started: 10.09.2015  07:42:04  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.7601.00  Calling process: D:\Service\JRE\jre-8u60-windows-i586.exe ===
MSI (c) (90:48) [07:42:04:015]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (90:48) [07:42:04:015]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (90:48) [07:42:04:015]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\LocalLow\Oracle\Java\jre1.8.0_60\jre1.8.0_60.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (90:48) [07:42:04:015]: Client-side and UI is none or basic: Running entire install on the server.
MSI (c) (90:48) [07:42:04:015]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (90:48) [07:42:04:015]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (90:48) [07:42:04:015]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (90:48) [07:42:04:015]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (68:78) [07:42:04:031]: Running installation inside multi-package transaction C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\LocalLow\Oracle\Java\jre1.8.0_60\jre1.8.0_60.msi
MSI (s) (68:78) [07:42:04:031]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (s) (68:F4) [07:42:04:031]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (s) (68:F4) [07:42:04:031]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (s) (68:F4) [07:42:04:031]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\LocalLow\Oracle\Java\jre1.8.0_60\jre1.8.0_60.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (s) (68:F4) [07:42:04:031]: Note: 1: 2203 2: C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\LocalLow\Oracle\Java\jre1.8.0_60\jre1.8.0_60.msi 3: -2147287037 
MSI (s) (68:F4) [07:42:04:031]: MainEngineThread is returning 3
MSI (s) (68:78) [07:42:04:031]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (68:78) [07:42:04:031]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (68:78) [07:42:04:031]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (68:78) [07:42:04:031]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (68:78) [07:42:04:031]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (68:78) [07:42:04:031]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\InProgress 3: 2 
MSI (s) (68:78) [07:42:04:031]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\InProgress 3: 2 
MSI (s) (68:78) [07:42:04:031]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (s) (68:78) [07:42:04:031]: Restoring environment variables
MSI (c) (90:48) [07:42:04:031]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (90:48) [07:42:04:031]: MainEngineThread is returning 3
=== Verbose logging stopped: 10.09.2015  07:42:04 ===
```

our system runs the MSI with the following parameters:

```
jre-8u60-windows-i586.exe /s /L D:\Service\JRE\setup8u60.log
```

So far we ensured that there is no other installation running and that java is completetly removed beforehand as those were the only indications we found on the web.

Any tip would be helpful!

Comment: Are you using the exe file? I always prefer using the msi file if possible. Java does not offer the msi package, but it's very easy to extract it: http://www.74k.org/extracting-java-msi-from-java-exe

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 is becoming a pain in the ass for massive deployment.

This time 
I think it's a problem with the exe in 8u60, it worked before with 8u51 and 8u45.

If you see the log, It tries to open the msi on C:\windows\system32 and I assume it finds nothing there.
In Java 8u51 and 45... it worked because it tried to open on C:\windows\syswow64.

**Workaround that worked for me:**

- Extract the MSI -> http://www.techygeekshome.co.uk/2014/01/java-msi-extraction-from-windows-7-and.html
  The real path where will be located is %userprofile%\AppData\LocalLow\Oracle\Java\jre1.8.0_60
- Copy the msi to C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\LocalLow\Oracle\Java\jre1.8.0_60\jre1.8.0_60.msi
- Execute the installer (.exe) as you did. In my case I use:

  ```
  jre.exe INSTALL_SILENT=1 STATIC=0 AUTO_UPDATE=0 WEB_JAVA=1 WEB_JAVA_SECURITY_LEVEL=H WEB_ANALYTICS=0 EULA=0 REBOOT=0 NOSTARTMENU=1 /L C:\temp\jre-8u60.log
  ```

NOTE:
In 8u51 and 8u45 I also needed to copy java.setting.cfg to C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java before installation:
http://www.edugeek.net/forums/enterprise-software/143767-java-8-update-25-silent-install-via-sccm-10.html#post1333454

**To try it correctly**:

I assume you're running the exe as SYSTEM (SCCM maybe?).
In order to test it you can try to install it in a CMD as SYSTEM, open Console and execute:

```
    PSEXEC -i -s -d CMD
```

Then you can trye the exe installation.

Answer (score 0):

found this on another page - works great !
“The best way I have found is to install Java on a pc and then go to the appdata folder located here: C:\Users\username\AppData\LocalLow\Oracle\Java\jre1.8.0_60 and copy the jre1.8.0_60.msi file to your software folder used for SCCM deployment. Then set up your java Application for deployment using this msi file. Add your switches or whatever you need. I have been doing this for many years and have never had an issue deploying Java to the thousands of computers I manage.  “

Answer (score 0):

For me this error was because the installer could not find the .CAB files. When you extract the .msi you also need to grab the CAB files and put them in the same folder as the .msi when you call it.